# Insert into a table using CTE

Tags: sql

I found a nice piece of code creating a table with 100.000 test records. I'm completely lost with the syntax. I know it's a table constructor (from values(0).....), I know it's a cross join (the part with: CreateTable as tt, CreateTable as st etc...), but how do I understand the formula creating 100.000 records?

```
truncate table t2;

with CreateTable as
(
    select d 
    from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as d(d)
)
insert into t2(col1)
    select 10000 * tt.d + 1000 * st.d + 100 * h.d + 10 * t.d + s.d + 1
    from CreateTable as tt, CreateTable as st, CreateTable as h, CreateTable as t, CreateTable as s;
```

Comment: You can try to use `top 100000 ` when you do `select ... insert into`

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking, the query is simply an (old fashioned) cartesian product - I wouldn't call it *nice* at all.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: thanks for your answers. 1) I'm using MS SQL Server 2) as I said: I know it's a cartesian product and a table constructor 3) sure enough: 5 x iteration = 10 ^ 5 = 100000.

Comment: sorry, once again:
thanks for your answers. 1) I'm using MS SQL Server 2) as I said: I know it's a cartesian product and a table constructor 3) sure enough: 5 x iteration = 10 ^ 5 = 100000.
4) the question is the select part (10000 * tt.d ..), it creates: (?): 1,11111,22221,33331,44441,55551,66661,77771,88881,99991. When I join it 5 x with itself (cartesian product) it creates 100.000 records but not: 1,2,3,...100000.
So my problem is to understand this (probably) simple algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula to create 100 000 lines.

Just reading this I feel that: you begin with a table of 10 rows, then the code joins the table with itself with aliases (tt, st, h, t and s).

So there is 10 rows at the beginning and after 4 joins, this ends with 10^5 rows (100 000 rows).

As Stu said, this is a cartesian product.

Comment: Then I think this is a correct answer to your question. no?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server:

Another possible solution without using cte, thought this might be helpful for others in future

```
create table dbo.test_table(id int)

declare @id int = 1

WHILE @id < 100001 
BEGIN  
        
        INSERT INTO test_table(id)
        SELECT  @id
        SET @id = @id+1
END
```

Comment: This might be a (poor) alternative to the task performed by the question, but that wasn't the question being asked.